# Find "interruption" in dates with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with fields: VALID_FROM - VALID_UP - CLIENT

Lets say

```
 2005 - 2006 - Smith
 2006 - 2009 - Smith
 2010 - 2013 - Smith
 2013 - 2014 - Smith
 2015 - 2016 - Smith
 2016 - 2017 - Smith
 2017 - today - Smith
 2014 - today - Bob
```

What I want to find is the start date after the interruption. In this case:

```
2015 - 2016 - Smith
2014 - today - Bob
```

There might me hundreds of entries - I always need the FIRST interruption, going back from today.

Any chance I can do this in (Oracle) SQL?

Comment: Why would `2015 - 2016 - Smith` be the `FIRST interruption`? Why wouldn't `2010 - 2013 - Smith` be the `FIRST`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I think the key is "need the FIRST interruption, ***going back from today.***

Comment: Ah. Helps if I read more thoroughly. Thanks. :-)

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? This type of question has a simple and efficient solution using `match_recognze`, but that is only available since Oracle version 12.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach here is to use the `LAG()` analytic function to check each row for an interrupted date, for each client.  Then, subquery this to restrict to the latest interruption only.  It would be difficult to explain the query below in words, but if you run each piece, starting with the innermost subquery and building up outwards, it should make sense to you.

```
SELECT
    t.VALID_FROM,
    t.VALID_UP,
    t.CLIENT
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT ORDER BY VALID_FROM DESC) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t.*,
            LAG(VALID_UP) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT ORDER BY VALID_FROM) v_lag
        FROM yourTable t
    ) t
    WHERE t.VALID_FROM <> COALESCE(t.v_lag, -1)
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

**Output:**

[image]

I can never seem to get Rextester working for Oracle, but I did manage to get a demo working for SQL Server:

## Demo

Comment: The output should be Smith: 2015-2017 - maybe a MAX() wrapper could help?

Comment: @number005 - if that is what you need, then that is what you should say in your initial question. In your post you said "What I want to find is **the start date** after the interruption." That has nothing to do with showing "today" as the `VALID_UP` value.

Comment: @mathguy Once again, someone (not sure who) edited the question and changed the expected output.  I tried to fix it.

Comment: @mathguy You are right. I was assuming that "From today backwards" would indicate it. The solution already helped :) Thanks. Now I have to transfer it to ODI (oracle data integrator), which is not so easy.